# Oracle: Savepoints within execute immediate and ORA-01086

Tags: oracle, plsql, dynamic-sql

Does anybody know, why i get an *ORA-01086: savepoint 'SPX' never established in this session or is invalid* in the following Code?

```
begin 
    rollback; --clear all Transactions
    execute immediate 'begin
                           savepoint SPX;
                           raise no_data_found;  
                       end;';
exception when no_data_found then 
    rollback to savepoint SPX;
end;
```

It is working if i don't use execute immediate:

```
begin 
    rollback; --clear all Transactions
    begin
        savepoint SPX;
        raise no_data_found;  
    end;
exception when no_data_found then 
    rollback to savepoint SPX;
end;
```

So is this an expected behaviour or is this something like a bug?

I'm using *Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production*

**Update:**
the following Example is also working, it uses dynamic SQL combined with Savepoints:

```
begin 
    rollback; --clear all Transactions
    execute immediate 'begin
                           savepoint SPX;
                       end;';
    rollback to savepoint SPX;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that before the exception propagates to the outer block, an implicit ROLLBACK occurs, which removes the savepoint that the block had created.

Here is an example that reproduces the problem but using static SQL:

```
begin 
    rollback; --clear all Transactions
    savepoint SPX;
    rollback;
    raise no_data_found;
exception when no_data_found then 
    rollback to savepoint SPX;
end;

ORA-01086: savepoint 'SPX' never established in this session or is invalid ORA-06512: at line 7
```

Unfortunately you're stuck with this behaviour; dynamic SQL must be run within its own context, and if it raises an exception (and doesn't handle it), a ROLLBACK will be issued.

You will need to create the savepoint before running the dynamic SQL; alternatively, you can suppress the ORA-01086 error:

```
begin 
    rollback; --clear all Transactions
    execute immediate 'begin
                           savepoint SPX;
                           raise no_data_found;  
                       end;';
exception when no_data_found then 
  begin
    rollback to savepoint SPX;
  exception when others then
    if sqlcode != -1086 /*savepoint never established*/ then
      raise;
    end if;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the [Oracle Doc on the SAVEPOINT statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/savepoint_statement.htm) ist says:

> The SQL SAVEPOINT statement can be embedded as static SQL in PL/SQL.

So I think this can be considered as an expected behaviour.

Comment: I've updated my Question with an Example using dynamic SQL and Savepoints without Exceptions.

Comment: Good thinking! Seems like in your first example with the exception raised the EXECUTE failed as a block, detroying the Savepoint.

Comment: The fact that SAVEPOINT is valid in PL/SQL is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: The keyword here is STATIC. The original question was if there is a difference between static and dynamic SQL.